# Removing quotation marks from list items

Tags: python, list

I am running this program:

```
f = open( "animals.txt", "r")
g = f.read()
g1 = g.split(',') #turning the file into list
print g1
```

And I want this to come out:

```
['ELDEN', 'DORSEY', 'DARELL', 'BRODERICK', 'ALONSO']
```

Instead, I am getting this:

```
['"ELDEN"', '"DORSEY"', '"DARELL"', '"BRODERICK"', '"ALONSO"']
```

Does anyone know how to remove the inner quotes

Comment: Also, you are not currently closing the file when you are done with it.  You need to do `f.close()` at the end or open the file using a [with-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to have it be automatically closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try a list comprehension which allows you to effectively and efficiently reassign the list to an equivalent list with quotes removed.

```
g1 = [i.replace('"', '') for i in g1] # remove quote from each element
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily strip off the quote characters using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
f = open( "animals.txt", "r")
g = f.read()
g1 = [x.strip('"') for x in g.split(',')]
print g1
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['"ELDEN"', '"DORSEY"', '"DARELL"', '"BRODERICK"', '"ALONSO"']
>>> [x.strip('"') for x in lst]
['ELDEN', 'DORSEY', 'DARELL', 'BRODERICK', 'ALONSO']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

if the list contains only numbers in quotes then cast every element like this:

```
foo = [int(i) for i in my_list] # cast every element in the list
```

ORIGINAK:

```
['1','4','9']
```

AFTER:

```
[1,4,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is creating your file in the first place?  It looks as though you have a kind of CSV where either all elements, or at least all string elements, are surrounded by quotation marks.  As such, you have at least a couple of choices for moving the quotation-mark removal "upstream" from what most of the other answers here are suggesting:

1. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

> ```
> import csv
> with open('animals.txt', 'r') as f:
>     g = csv.reader(f)
>     g1 = g.next()
> ```

2. Include the quotation marks in your `split()`, and chop off the leading and trailing quotes first:

> ```
> with open('animals.txt', 'r') as f:
>     g = f.read()
>     g1 = g[1:-1].split('","')
> ```

The first option may be somewhat more "heavyweight" than what you're looking for, but it's more robust (and still not *that* heavy).  Note that the second option assumes that your file does NOT have a trailing newline at the end.  If it does, you have to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should go back to the source.

Apparently your file contains the text `"ELDEN", "DORSEY", "DARELL", "BRODERICK", "ALONSO"` (etc). We can delegate the parsing:

```
import ast

with open("animals.txt") as inf:
    g1 = ast.literal_eval("[" + inf.read() + "]")
```