# Access variables through their name as string in Python

Tags: python

I would like to run a function with a list parameter :

```
param = ['a', 'b', 'c']
myFunction(param)
```

But a, b and c must be dynamic so I would like to remove the quotes to get this :

```
param = [a, b, c]
myFunction(param)
```

How can I do that ?

PS : I tried the solutions of this question but it didn't work [Removing quotation marks from list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376538/removing-quotation-marks-from-list-items)

Comment: Are you saying that `a`, `b` and `c` are variables that are defined in your code, and `param` should be a list containing those 3 variables?

Comment: Yes this is the case

Comment: Please rephrase your question to avoid misleading future readers. What you need is to evaluate variables using their names, not remove quotes

Comment: Then why not writing a, b, c directly?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/19122532/6360875

Comment: your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445983/4092588)

Comment: Sounds like you want a dictionary like `{'a': 3, 'b': 2}`, not separate variables `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to actually call `myFunction` with parameters `a`, `b` and `c` (assuming these are actually being defined earlier).

One way of doing this is:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
param = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def myFunction(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

myFunction(*[globals()[s] for s in param])
# returns: 6
```

## EDIT:

As people have suggested, a safe way of doing this would be through `globals()` (or `locals()` using a slightly different construct). Otherwise, you could use `eval()` which is more powerful, but also potentially less safe.

Comment: *Please* don't use `eval` when `globals` would be sufficient. Beginners will copy your `eval` without thinking and open themselves up to code injection.

Comment: In my case, there is no code injection issue, good for me ;)

Comment: @CharlesR this still is very bad practice, have a look at the duplicate, use `locals()`. It is exactly what it is meant for

Comment: @Aran-Fey you are right, I just typed faster than I should have. @OlivierMelançon `locals()` would not work inside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

`'str'`'s cannot be converted to variable names, however if you do have th variables and your goal is to pass each variable to a function this is possible

```
def addition(x):
    return x + 1

a = 1 b = 2 c = 3

param = [a, b, c] 
print([addition(i) for i in param])
# [2, 3, 4]
```

The entire list could be passed as well like so

```
def addition(x):
    return sum(x)

a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

param = [a, b, c]
print(addition(param))
# 6
```

Comment: It is wrong that a string cannot be converted to variable. You can use `locals()['a']`. Although, I agree OP just should not rely on strings

Comment: @OlivierMelançon noted, every lookup I did involved a tedious process to convert a `str` to variable name will look into this, ty